# dice animation - showing numbers like on a countdown

Tags: java, multithreading, animation, random, dice

I have a simple dice roller that displays the result in a JLabel. I'd like an animation of random numbers showing and slowing down until one is picked.
No matter what I try, I cannot get the JLabel to display the numbers, it will only display the final one.
Also, when you roll the same number as the one before, there's no way of telling because nothing changes in the Jaleb

One of my attempts:

```
private void rollDice(int lower, int upper) {

    try {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int int_random = rand.nextInt(lower,upper);
            Thread.sleep(i*20);
            lblDice.setText(Integer.toString(int_random));
            contentPane.paintComponents(lblDice.getGraphics());
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

Comment: You are blocking the Swing thread from doing anything until your method returns.  It has no opportunity to paint the label at the intermediate stages.  Do this in another thread or use a timer or something.  Use SwingUtilities.invokeLater to update the label.

Comment: Your sleep is also very short if you expect users to see that is happening.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it. The function is called with a button press. Where should I create a second thread? And what should I put in it?

Comment: The simplest thing to do would be to use a SwingTimer to update the label.  Saves you needing to manage threads on your own and synchronize with the GUI thread.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html